# C# XmlReader very slow

Tags: c#, xml, performance, rss, xmlreader

I try to read an RSS feed from my Website (Wordpress) this process takes very long (around 21000 ms).

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
        SyndicationFeed newsFeed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        int count = 0;
        List<NewsArticle> articleList = new List<NewsArticle>();
        foreach (SyndicationItem newsArticle in newsFeed.Items)
        {
            if (count < 3)
            {
                NewsArticle article = new NewsArticle(newsArticle.Title.Text, newsArticle.Summary.Text);
                articleList.Add(article);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

The problem is the XmlReader (when I create it).
Why it tooks so long? When I´m Opening the RSS Feed in the Browser, it is super fast.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide the feed url?

Comment: Sure: https://chronos-gaming.de/?feed=rss2

Comment: ~100ms on my side in release mode. Try to split your code in two part. One for downloading the feed, and one for parsing. It will give you independent measurement. But I think it's mostly a network issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to Download the String with a WebClient. This also takes around 21000ms (I´ve debugged it). I tried it also with Google, there it takes only 320ms.

Comment: You are probably using a cookie with the browser which speeding use the response.  I would try linq xml : XDocument.Load(URL);

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it did not work, the same loading time. Other RSS-Feeds, based on the same Server work fine.